# Is there a way to click on a button by just knowing the href? With no id or value to clearly distinguish. With Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am trying to work on a side personal project for automating email accounts. I am relatively new to Selenium and am having trouble clicking the signup button. I have tried the two following methods but none of them seem to be working.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@link= "https://protonmail.com/signup"]').click()
driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SIGN UP').click()
```

This is what I see when I click inspect element on the sign up button by the way. There is no id or value that can will easily classify the button.

```
<a href="signup" class="btn btn-default btn-short">SIGN UP </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `href` attribute like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="signup"]')
```

You can also locate by the text, but you need to take the space into account, so use partial text

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('SIGN UP')
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Would you mind explaining to me why this is the proper way to approach this situation?

Comment: @xHect the `href` is an attribute, and its value is `signup`. You need to use the attribute as is.

Comment: ooh ok, thank you for your assistance @Guy

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use tag+value selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[value='SIGN UP ']").click()
```

Comment: There is no `value` in the html.